# Generate acronym from phrase

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

I've posted the code for the following question. What could be improved?

> Q: Write a program that allows the user to type in a phrase and then
>   outputs the acronym for that phrase.
>
> Note: The acronym should be all uppercase, even if the words in the
>   phrase are not capitalized.

```
def main():

    ## input the phrase
    phrase = input("Enter the phrase: ")

    ## split the phrase into substrings
    phrase_split = phrase.split()


    acronym = ""

    ## iterate through every substring
    for i in phrase_split:
        acronym = acronym + i[0].upper()

    print("The acronym for your phrase is ",acronym + ".")

main()
```

Comment: What would be – and what _should_ be – an acronym for a phrase with part in parentheses (or in dashes), like this one?

Comment: Is this aimed at being a whiteboard exercise?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. You should name your function more descriptively, maybe `acronym`.
2. You should wrap your code under a [`if __name__ == "__main__":`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) guard to allow importing parts of your script from other scripts.
3. You should separate the user input from the logic.
4. Use [`docstrings`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) to describe what functions do.
5. Use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) together with a [generator expression](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/python-list-comprehensions-vs-generator-expressions-cef70ccb49db) to join multiple strings.
6. Use the new [`f-strings`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) introduced in Python 3.6.

Taking this gives you:

```
def user_input():
    """Get the user input for a phrase"""
    return input("Enter the phrase: ")

def acronym(words):
    """Turn a list of words into an acronym"""
    return "".join(word[0] for word in words).upper()

def main():
    words = user_input().split()
    print(f"The acronym for your phrase is {acronym(words)}.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You've not said but you did apply to your code: "Call upper only once instead of once per word".

Comment: Function (user_input) should has a verb in its name, because functions do something. Also, I would not have separate function for getting user input, because this is impure part of program and I think appropriate place for that is function main().

I would have functions for pure part and main() for impure one.
Pure part: from input string to acronym.
Impure part: getting input from user and printing result

Answer (score 3):

I would rather write the code as soft as the requested exercise was:

```
def acronym(phrases):
    acronym = ""
    for word in phrases.split():
        acronym = acronym + word[0].upper()
    return acronym

def main():
    phrases = input("Enter a phrase: ")
    print(acronym(phrases))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I changed some variable names to make everything more readable and removed something useless to shorten the code.

> You should wrap your code under a `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard to allow importing parts of your script from other scripts.

as the other guy said.

I can bear that you are a novice and the first times what matters is to make a good and clear code, so you can get the idea next times you have to do something similar.

If it was asked to make the code the shortest possible, then I would suggest something like this:

```
def main():
    data = input('Enter a phrase: ')
    data = [i[0] for i in data.upper().split(' ')] 
    print(''.join(data))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here we split every word, get its first letter and use [str.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to print a concatenation of the strings.